# How to insert data into array in PHP prepare statment?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I am trying to insert data into array before using it using prepare statement pdo.

Here is what I have done :

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM settings"); 
$stmt->execute(array());
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    htmlspecialchars($row['site_name']);
                    htmlspecialchars($row['site_desc']);
                    htmlspecialchars($row['site_url']);
unset($stmt);
```

Usaqe :

```
$row['site_name'];
```

It works fine, but I feel like I am missing an importand thing.

Here is my question:
Do I have to declare all values in `$stmt->execute(array());` 
Like so:`$stmt->execute(array(':site_name'=>$site_name, ':site_name'=>$site_name,));` before using it ?

And how to do like this ?

```
 $a['site_name'] = htmlspecialchars($row['site_name']);
 $a['site_desc'] = htmlspecialchars($row['site_desc']);
 $a['site_url'] = htmlspecialchars($row['site_url']);
```

Usaqe :

```
$a['site_name'];
```

I wached videos and tutorials but couldnt make second example works.

Comment: as you are not using any variables in the sql you could simply use `$pdo->query( $sql );` and no, you do not need to define items in an array to access them in the recordset - they will be there naturally because you select all items. Your output array is however overwriting `$a['site_name']` with different values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there are no variables ( generally user input ) being used there is strictly no need to use a `prepared statement` so you could simply use the regular `query` method.

```
$a=array();

$sql = 'select * from `settings`;';
$res = $pdo->query( $sql );
if( $res ){
    while( $rs=$pdo->fetch( PDO::FETCH_OBJ ) ){
        $a['site_name']=$rs->site_name;
        $a['site_desc']=$rs->site_desc;
        $a['site_url']=$rs->site_url;
    }
}
```

If however you had some additional parameters to the query ( generally a `where` clause ) you would probably want to use a `prepared statement` and it is there that you would define a `placeholder` and later assign a value to it for use in the `execute` method

```
$sql='select * from `settings` where `site_name`=:site_name;';
$params=array(':site_name'=>'example.com');
$stmt=$pdo->prepare( $sql );
if( $stmt ){
    $res=$pdo->execute( $params );
    if( $res ){
        while( $rs=$stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_OBJ ) ){
            $a['site_name']=$rs->site_name;
            $a['site_desc']=$rs->site_desc;
            $a['site_url']=$rs->site_url;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I was away! Thanks for quick answer I wil try your examples now.

Comment: I am having this error in your first example : `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDO::fetch()` I have turned PDO::FETCH_ASSOC from your OBJ but still having same error when I use it in page like this `php echo $a['site_name']; `@RamRaider

Answer (score 0):

use `$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))` with Raim's answer